# How to put 3d cursor in corner without corner?

Tags: 3d-cursor

When i try to use 'g' key in 3dcursor mode, it doesn't work. I can only use right mouse click, than i can use snapping on z axis. but it's not accurate! the cursor moves when i click on it...How can i do that?

[image: i need to put 3d cursor in blue circle]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! From my quick testing, the cursor should snap back to where you selected if from when you press Z. That's what it looks like in the gif too. Are you sure it was in the center when you started?

Comment: when you hold right mouse button, it starts from your click location, not in previous location

Comment: You could create temporary geometry and snap cursor to that.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T57208
cursor currently in development, xyz controls will solve the problem) well, I answered myself ))